# FCM, доставка push при запущеном приложении

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messages

Всем добрый день!

Возникла проблема с доставкой push на устройства (Android) с помощью Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Суть проблемы, когда приложение запущено (foreground) push сообщения не приходят на устройство. Если же приложение закрыть или свернуть, то сообщения приходят исправно. Прошу помощи в прояснении причин такого поведения!

Сделано все по инструкции для ОС Android из документации Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Когда приложение запущено, уведомление отправляется не сразу в notification center, а в приложение, вам нужно поймать это уведомление с помощью метода onMessageReceived. Рекомендую погуглить по этому методу

Answer (score 0):

Создай класс для получения push уведомлений

```
   public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
 }
 private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

 Uri defaultSoundUri=     RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.icon))
    .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setContentText(messageBody)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
 }
 }
```

И пропиши в манифесте

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```